# How to pass a char array to a method and return a boolean value

Tags: java, methods, boolean, palindrome, arrays

I am trying to write a program which checks whether a word is a palindrome or not. My code compiles butthe code in the isItPalindrome method doesn't seem to be run at all. I'm hoping someone can point out where i have gone wrong. Here is my code:

```
class Main
{
public static void main ( String args[] )
{
    System.out.print ("#Enter word");
    String word = BIO.getString();

    String wordLowerCase = word.toLowerCase();                                        // converts word to lower case (only way i could think of to ignore case)
    char letters[] = wordLowerCase.toCharArray();                                     // converts string into an array of character


    while ( !word.equals ("END")){
        if (isItPalindrome(letters) == true)
        {
            System.out.print (""+word+"");
            System.out.println ("   is a palindrome");

        }
        else if (isItPalindrome(letters) == false)
        {
            System.out.print (""+word+"");
            System.out.println ("   is not a palindrome");
        }

        System.out.print ("#Enter word");
        word = BIO.getString();

    }

}

public static boolean isItPalindrome ( char letters[]){

    boolean palindrome = true;
    if (letters.length%2 == 0){
        for (int index=0; index<letters.length/2-1; index++)                              //index will finish at letters/2  
        {
            if (letters[index] != letters[letters.length-index-1])                                       //checks if index is the same as its opposite letter
            {
                return false;

            }
            else                                                                         //if any pairs of letters are not in ascending order then it returns fasle and breaks out of the loop
            {
                palindrome = true;

            }

        }
    }
    else{
        for (int index = 0; index < (letters.length-1)/2-1; index++)
        {
            if (letters[index] != letters[letters.length-index-1]){

                return false;

            }
            else{

                palindrome = true;
            }  

        }
    }

    return palindrome;
}
```

}

Comment: _doesn't seem to be run at all._ How can you tell?

Comment: also, you never update `letters`, so you only ever have the letters from the first word.

Comment: What is BIO (word = BIO.getString();)?

Comment: also, remove the `-1` (all three of them) (and you don't need to make 2 different cases based on `letters.length%2`, because `letters.length%2 == 1` -> `(letters.length-1)/2 == letters.length/2`)

Comment: Try adding System.out.println() into your isItPalindrome and also print the values of each of the characters being compared. That way  you can figure out what's wrong with the logic yourself. Also, instead of invoking the method twice, it would be simpler to invoke once and assign the return value to a boolean.

Comment: The question needs to be fixed since title indicates char Array yet the question and discussion focus on String Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues in the main-method, for example the char-array was never updated and the palindrome-method was far to complicated, here is the working version:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("#Enter word: ");
    String word = BIO.getString();

    while (!word.equals("END")) {
        char[] letters = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

        if (isItPalindrome(letters) == true) {
            System.out.println(word + "   is a palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.print(word + "   is not a palindrome");
        } // OR
        // Use this one-liner instead of the if:
        // System.out.println(word + isItPalindrome(letters) ?
        //                     "   is a palindrome" : "   is not a palindrome");

    System.out.print("#Enter word: ");
    word = BIO.getString();
    }

}

public static boolean isItPalindrome(char letters[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length / 2; i++) {
        if (letters[i] != letters[letters.length - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much that's a huge help, I didn't realize i was over-complicating things quite so much!

Answer (score 1):

Besides the initial word, your character array `letters` never reflects the current `word` in your while loop inside your main method. I don't know what you mean when you say your method "doesn't seem to be run at all" but I assume that you meant it's being run with the wrong output. This is one reason why. Be sure to call

```
wordLowerCase = word.toLowerCase();
letters = wordLowerCase.toCharArray();
```

every iteration of the while loop.

Side note: In your `isItPalindrome` method, you do not even need any of the else statements or the boolean `palindrome` at all. Simply `return false` if you ever find a case when the word is not a palindrome like you currently are. Then, if you have gotten to the end of the word, it must be a palindrome and you can `return true`.

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer the question that's in the title:

`public boolean palindrome(char C)`

Has a return type of `boolean` but requires that you pass it a Character.

Second:

You're over-complicating things in the way that you reverse the words to check them. You could simply take the word, as a String, and take it apart, putting it into an array of `Characters`. Then put each `char` variable into a `Stack`. Then as you take them out of the stack, piece by piece, copy them to another array of `Character`s.